# Memory Leak from iterating Opencv frames

Tags: java, opencv

I am using the java wrapper of OpenCV. I tried to write an Iterator over frames of a film. My problem is that the iterator is a huge memory leak. Here is a very simplified version of the iterator, which has this leak:

```
public static final class SimpleIt implements Iterator<Mat> {

    private final VideoCapture capture;
    boolean hasNext;

    public SimpleIt(final VideoCapture capture) {
        this.capture = capture;
        hasNext = capture.grab();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return hasNext;
    }

    @Override
    public Mat next() {
        final Mat mat = new Mat();
        capture.retrieve(mat);
        hasNext = capture.grab();
        return mat;
    }
}
```

I Iterate over this code using this loop:

```
    final VideoCapture vc = new VideoCapture("/path/to/file");
    final SimpleIt it = new SimpleIt(vc);
    while (it.hasNext) {
        it.next();
    }
```

Just iterating will increase memory consumption linear. I see that the problem is the first line in the next()-Method. It always creates a new Mat. But speaking of java alone, this Mat will run out of scope as soon as the iterating code iterates to the next image.

I could overcome the problem, by not using a new Mat every time, but overwriting always the same Mat-Object, like this:

```
    private final VideoCapture capture;
    private final Mat mat = new Mat();
    boolean hasNext;

    @Override
    public Mat next() {
        capture.retrieve(mat);
        hasNext = capture.grab();
        return mat;
    }
```

But now the last frame which was given by the iterator will be overwritten. Thus, I cannot hold it outside for later use, if I am interested in this single frame. I could copy it, of course, but that would also be expensive.

I assume that the problem is that the garbage collector will not destroy the Mat objects, because it does not recognize the memory consumption, since it is not java heap space. Calling mat.release() in the loop will help, but of course in real code this means I will have no garbage collection for my Mat objects.

Anybody has an idea how to do it?

Edit:

Since it seems not to be clear what the problem with my second solution is, I write it down more explicitly. Think about the following code, using the iterator:

```
    final VideoCapture vc = new VideoCapture("/path/to/file");
    final SimpleIt it = new SimpleIt(vc);
    int i = 0;
    Mat save = null;
    while (it.hasNext) {
        final Mat next = it.next();
        if (i == 10) {
            save = next;
            Highgui.imwrite("/path/to/10.png", save);
        } else if (i == 30) {
            Highgui.imwrite("/path/to/30.png", save);
        }
        i++;
    }
```

With the second version of the iterator, 10.png, and 30.png will be different images. But that's obviously not what was intended.

Comment: Do you run out of memory? If not then this isn't a leak - the GC will run when it needs to.

Comment: Yes, I do so. In a few seconds some Gigabyte are full.

Answer (score 17):

**You should really call `mat.release()`.**

I have very similar problem to yours in my application. The frame rate was so high that java heap grew up to total available system memory, which sometimes led to JVM crash. GC was simply too slow, and I didn't have any mechanism to check of available memory and wait if that wasn't sufficient.

One solution was to decrease the frame rate by simply using `Thread.sleep()` which of course didn't seem to be acceptable. But it helped GC to do it's job on time.

Finally using `mat.release()` fixed the problem.

You don't have to worry about garbage collection of Mat objects, because this call deallocates only underlying data. Java object wrapper will be disposed by GC when the right time comes.

Comment: Currently my solution works for me, though I feel very uneasy about it. The problem wit `release()` is, that it will be very difficult to determine when a ceretain Mat is out of use. I do a lot of processing with them, passing them to various parts of the system for different analysis. Many parts don't know if the others use the same Mat, too. That's probably how java developers design their systems. Though >99% of the frames are unintersting and discarded directly after the first analysis step - so maybe I should at least release those.

Comment: I've just came up with an idea that you can wrap `Mat` object in some kind of reference counter object. With e.g. `acquire()` and `realese()` methods you can handle count of active references to `Mat`. When this count comes to zero, you will call `Mat.release()` to free memory.

Comment: @lukk I speak under correction, but one thing to note is that Mat already uses a reference counter for managing the underlying memory, since opencv shares Mat references quite intensely : http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.11/org/opencv/core/Mat.html - I think you can create a new Mat that references the old one with `new Mat(m.getNativeObjAddr());`

Answer (score 17):

I just want to add my $0.02 as I bumped into this issue when writing an application that will run for a long.

Mat.release() is called automatically when the Java Mat-wrapper is garbage collected. However, since the Java wrapper is very small compared to the natively allocated object, it might not be garbage-collected fast enough.

Therefore, you could either do `Mat.release()` when you know you are done with an object or call `System.gc()` at regular intervals to force removal of unused objects.

Comment: This strategy appears to have worked for me. Java thought it was allocating like like 1 Object Reference and 1 long for each mat. However, the C++ side was doing MUCH more. Since Java couldn't see that memory, it didn't know how little memory there was to play with. You have to force a call to `Mat.finalize()`. `System.gc()` will do that.

Comment: When I was customizing the openCV 3 tutorials I had to add the line "modified.release();" right after "Utils.matToBitmap(modified, mCacheBitmap);" in the CameraBridgeViewBase.java file and now all runs stable. I also call System.gc() in onCameraFrame as suggested.

Answer (score 7):

System.gc(); doesn't work for me.

I have add the line:

System.runFinalization();

A Codesnippet:

```
    startGC--;
    if (startGC==0) {
        System.gc();
        System.runFinalization();
        startGC=100;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

It seems, there is no good solution. I experimented with it now for quite some hours. The best I came up with was calling the garbage collector on a regular basis like this:

```
    int count = 0;

    @Override
    public Mat next() {
        final Mat result = mat;
        mat = new Mat();
        capture.retrieve(mat);
        hasNext = capture.grab();
        if (++count % 200 == 0) {
            System.gc();
        }
        return result;
```

Since this works, it indicates that my assumption was correct, java does not recognize the RAM allocated from C, and thus does not call the GC, even though the RAM of the machine is running out.

This is not a very good solution, because it might not be very stable. If anybody else has a better idea, I am interested.

Answer (score 1):

I would modify your `.hasNext` method to:

```
public boolean hasNext() {
    return hasNext;
}
```

And then the method you described, copied below, should work fine... You will iterate until nothing is left, at which point you can assign that last image to a new Mat object...

```
public Mat next() {
    capture.retrieve(mat);
    hasNext = capture.grab();
    return mat;
}
```

and then:

```
final VideoCapture vc = new VideoCapture("/path/to/file");
final SimpleIt it = new SimpleIt(vc);
final Mat lastFrame = new Mat();
while (it.hasNext) {
    lastFrame = it.next();
}
```

I do realize this creates additional memory usage. There is probably a way around this, but it should work fine...

Comment: That's not really the solution, I fear. That way you cannot save away a Mat you retrieved with the iteraor. See my edit to my question.