# How can I remove cv::Mat object from memory

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

Storing the `cv::mat` object causes a memory leak. How can I remove the mat from the memory. Seems the `cv::Mat.realease()` doesn't work.

MyClass.h

```
class MyClass {

public:
    cv::Mat nFrame;
    cv::Mat pGrayFrame;
    cv::Mat nGrayFrame;

    MyClass ();                     
    void     setCurrentFrame(cv::Mat& frame);
  } 
};
```

MyClass.cpp

```
MyClass::MyClass(void) {

}


void MyClass::setCurrentFrame(cv::Mat& frame) {
    //set frame and increment frameCount
    this->nFrame = frame;
    this->frameCount++;
}


void MyClass::saveCurrentFrame() {
    this->pGrayFrame = this->nGrayFrame;
}
```

this line causes memory leak:

```
this->nFrame = frame;
```

where `setCurrentFrame` is called in jni c++ function

Comment: Please show the code how you allocated the cv::mat object.

Comment: See this page: http://answers.opencv.org/question/14285/how-to-free-memory-through-cvmat/

Comment: Please explain in what way 'cv::Mat' causes a memory leak. 'cv::Mat.release()' doesn't free the memory only if if was allocated externally or if other 'Mat's contain references to that memory.

Comment: @anderas I updated the question with code. Yes the mat is allocated externally

Comment: @nv3 Please check the code update.

Comment: You need to delete the data that could be in the pointer of `this->nFrame` before you replace it via assignment. (if using external data)

Comment: How to delete that data please ? @RollenD'Souza

Comment: clarifying my previous comment: when we mean 'allocated externally', we are referring to the use of this [constructor](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a51615ebf17a64c968df0bf49b4de6a3a). Was that object constructed in this way?

Comment: @RollenD'Souza not the object is passed as parameter, where the JNI is called from java passing the Mat object like this ..
`JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL Java_com_adhamenaya_Native_run(JNIEnv * env,
  jobject obj,  jlong frame) {

   cv::Mat& inFrame = *(cv::Mat*) frame;}`  @RollenD'Souza

Comment: Okay. In that case the object is partly managed by Java which is important. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21050499/memory-leak-from-iterating-opencv-frames); although your case may not be as severe it is definitely relevant.

Comment: @RollenD'Souza I don't think so, because when I commented that line out, the memory leak disappeared

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92880/discussion-between-rollen-dsouza-and-adhamenaya).