# Memory Leak from Java OpenCv

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, memory-leaks

I process a frame...

```
@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) 
{
    Mat frame = inputFrame.rgba();
    mCameraCalculator.processFrame(frame);
    return frame;
}
```

which sets the frame to a new cropped Mat.

```
public void processFrame(Mat frame) 
{
    //fill frame outside of square center region
    Mat mask = new Mat(frame.size(), frame.type(), Scalar.all(255));  //create mask
    mask.submat(getCenterSquare(mask)).setTo(Scalar.all(0));        //init mask
    frame.setTo(Scalar.all(0), mask);   //fill

    mask.release()    //this does not solve the problem
}
```

This causes a memory leak, eventually crashing the application. Additionally, using Android Studio's Android Profiler, I see that the unreleased memory is native. What is going wrong?

Comment: I've not worked with opencv, but it appears that others have had this same issue, even after trying to use `release()`. See if the [various answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21050499/memory-leak-from-iterating-opencv-frames) might help?

Comment: How often does the size of the frame, or the size/position of the "center square" change? Consistent frame size means you need to allocate `mask` only once, consistent "center square" means you need to initialize it only once. (i.e. make it a member variable, and use lazy initialization when you get first frame, reuse the old one on others) | Of course, this doesn't fix whatever causes the leak, but at least you're minimizing the impact.